# iOS >> In-App-Purchase: How to store data externally to the App Bundle?

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-upload, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to learn how to use **In-App-Purchases** for my apps. I read in Apple documentation about the model that suggests holding the purchased items on a server, but they don't explain further regarding to how to actually build it.
Can anyone direct me to at least one of the followings?

1. **a tutorial that deals with it** - which servers to use, how to connect them with the app, how to secure my files so can only be approached from my app, how to do this direct communication between the server and the App Store
2. a **product** that does it - **Server + SDK**

Answer (score 1):

These tutorials will help you out -

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion is only for apps that already use a server to hold user info. If your user has an account in your database then you should save the fact that he bought a specific item in this same database.

Any server can do the job so just choose the one your familiar with.

Thanks to Google :
http://www.phpriot.com/articles/verifying-app-store-receipts-php-curl